# If a $K$-algebra is finite-dimensional and locally unital, then it is unital.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

I'm just checking this idea:

Let $K$ be a field. A $K$-algebra $A$ is said to be **unital** if there is an element $1_A$ such that $1_A a = a 1_A = a$ for every $a \in A$. The algebra $A$ is said to be **locally unital** if there is a set of idempotents $U \subseteq A$ (called local units) such that, for every finite subset $R \subseteq A$, there is a local unit $u_{_R} \in U$ such that $u_{_R} r = r u_{_R} = r$ for every $r \in R$.

Am I correct in thinking that we could happily replace "every finite subset" with "every finite-dimensional subspace"?

To show that the first definition is just as strong as the second:
Let $R = \{r_i\}_i$ be a (finite) basis for a subspace $S \subseteq A$. Then there is a local unit $u_{_R}$ and, for every $s = \sum_i k_i r_i \in S$, it's true that $u_{_R}s = su_{_R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly right.  In fact, you even can say "every finitely generated $K$-subalgebra", because a similar argument shows that $u_Rs=su_R=s$ for any $s$ in the $K$-subalgebra generated by $R$.

(For maximal generality, you can say that if $u_R$ is a unit for $R$, then $u_R$ is also a unit for the intersection of the left $K$-ideal and the right $K$-ideal generated by $R$, where by $K$-ideal I mean an ideal that is also a vector subspace.  I don't know any snappy way to describe all sets of this form you can get for finite $R$, though.)

Comment: Nice improvement!